# Target a specific key in an object

Tags: javascript

How can I target a specific key in an object, and do something else for the rest of the keys?

This is the HTML I want, notice the "@" symbol in name="@name":

```
<object>
  <param name="@name" value="someName" />
  <param name="class" value="someClass" />
</object>
```

How can I get the "@" symbol to render before it prints "name"?

Here is my HTML, Object and JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<object></object>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myObj = {
  name : 'someName',
  class : 'someClass'
};

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];
var element;

for (var i in myObj) {
  element = document.createElement('param');
  element.name = i;
  element.value = myObj[i];
  body.appendChild(element);
};
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C8vus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MDN article [Values, variables, and literals / Object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals):

> Object property names can be any string, including the empty string. If the property name would not be a valid JavaScript identifier, it must be enclosed in quotes. Property names that would not be valid identifiers also cannot be accessed with as a dot (`.`) property, but can be accessed and set with the array-like notation("`[]`").

So try this:

```
var myObj = {
  "@name" : 'someName',
  "class" : 'someClass'
};
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/C8vus/2/)